# Error When installing Tesseract 3.05 in Centos7 "error: Leptonica 1.74 or higher is required. Try to install libleptonica-dev package"

Tags: tesseract, centos7, leptonica

We had initially installed tesseract 3.04 in centos 7, and know switching to tesseract 3.05. We have un-installed the older versions and have already installed leptonica-1.75.3 downloaded from leptonica home site.

But, when we go for installing tesseract 3.05, we get following error 
checking for LEPTONICA... no
configure: error: Leptonica 1.74 or higher is required. Try to install libleptonica-dev package.

when running ./configure in console in tesseract-3.05.01 folder.

Need to know, where the issue is.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `configure` script uses `pkg-config` to see if the `leptonica` libs are installed (and have the required version).

After you have compiled and installed leptonica from source code you have to manually tell `pkg-config` where to find the `lept.pc` config file which is installed with leptonica. Set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable so it points to the location of `lept.pc`. If you installed leptonica to its default location you should do:

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/
```

before running `configure` for tesseract.

Comment: Saved my day. Cheers.

Comment: This is also needed when installing without root (in a local dir in $HOME). See https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling

Comment: I am getting the same error even after running export command

Comment: It's working fine. solved my biggest issue! Thanks, man...

Answer (score 0):

Mine would not work until I did the following copy commands. My Leptonica was installed in the **leptonica-1.83.0** directory, yours may be different.

cp /usr/local/**leptonica-1.83.0**/lib/pkgconfig/lept.pc /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/

cp -a /usr/local/**leptonica-1.83.0**/lib/*liblept* /usr/lib64

Also set:

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/**leptonica-1.83.0**/lib/pkgconfig

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/**leptonica-1.83.0**/lib

export LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR=/usr/local/**leptonica-1.83.0**/include/leptonica

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/**leptonica-1.83.0**/lib/pkgconfig

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/**leptonica-1.83.0**/lib/pkgconfig/

Then it worked.